Error No se ha podido cargar el informe con Crystal Report en maquina cliente
Hola buen día a todos!!!
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de escritorio con reportes en Crystal Reports a los cuakes les paso parámetros y le asigno mis valores de Base de Datos en codigo pero me pide valores de conexión a la BD
Ahora actualmente tengo dos maquinas cliente con Windows 7(Cpu1: Servidor con conexión a BD y Cpu2) y los reportes los tengo en Carpeta Compartida en la Cpu1 en donde la aplicación funciona a la perfección. Pero en la Cpu2 al momento de hacer el llamado de algún reporte me sale el siguiente error:


Ahora, yo se que el código esta bien por que en otras maquinas con Windows 10 o superior funciona a la perfección pero al probar en Windows 7 solo funciona en la maquina de Cpu1, a pesar de que la Cpu2 si tiene todos los permisos a la Carpeta Compartida.
¿Alguien tiene una respuesta a esto?
De antemano Gracias!!!

Te esta diciendo que esta mal el usuario y contraseña... estan bien???

@gbianchi si es correcto, el proyecto ya se provo en otras maquinas y funciona pero en esta con Windows 7 no

Pero da error de eso.. mucho mas no se te puede ayudar.. no importa que en otra PC funcione.. hay que eliminar cosas que hacen que no funcione ahi...

Saludos. Te comento; verifica que las credenciales del Crystal Reports a SQLServer estén directamente en el Reporte, y que la autenticación sea "SQL Server Authentication" no "Windows Authentication".
